# Inserting a record in a table having foreign key - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, form-for

```
class UserPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_job
    belongs_to :preference
end

class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :days
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :time_pref
    has_one :user_preference, :foreign_key => 'prefer1_id', :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "UserPreference"
    has_one :other_user_preference, :foreign_key => 'prefer2_id', :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "UserPreference"
end
```

I have these two models among others.
I'm trying to create a form where I can select a user and choose their preferences using drop down lists.

```
  %= form_for @user_preference, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
    <%= select_tag(:user_id, options_for_select(@user_options)) %>

<p><p> Preference 1 : 
<%= select_tag(:days_id, options_for_select(@day_options)) %>
<%= select_tag(:location_id, options_for_select(@building_options)) %>
<%= select_tag(:time_id, options_for_select(@time_slot_options)) %>
</p>
<p> Preference 2 : 
<%= select_tag(:days_id, options_for_select(@day_options)) %>
<%= select_tag(:location_id, options_for_select(@location_id)) %>
<%= select_tag(:time_pref_id, options_for_select(@time_pref_id)) %>
</p>

<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

And this allows me to choose an user and choose their preferences.
But, how do I use the foreign key to actually insert them into prefer1_id and prefer2_id? If I use the form as shown above, I don't get two different sets of preferences but just the choices from the second set of drop down lists.

I wish to do something like this(or some other code) to create a new record in the tables.

```
 def create
        @pref = preference.new(params[:pref])
        redirect_to @pref
      end
```

How to go about doing this? I'm a beginner to Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea. 
1. Update your association first.
2. Implement the form from using user preference and use nested form.
Your user preference class should be look like this:

```
class UserPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_job
    has_one :preference_one, :foreign_key => 'prefer1_id', :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "UserPreference"
   has_one :preference_two, :foreign_key => 'prefer2_id', :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "UserPreference"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :preference_one # configure your options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :preference_two # configure your options
end


class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ...
    belongs_to :user_preference, :foreign_key => 'prefer1_id', :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "UserPreference"
    belongs_to :other_user_preference, :foreign_key => 'prefer2_id', :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "UserPreference"
end
```

Now in your controller:

```
def new
   @user_preference = UserPreference.new
   @user_preference.build_preference_one
   @user_preference.build_preference_two
end

def create
    @user_preference = UserPreference.new(user_preference_params)
    # make sure you add your nested attributes on the permitted param list.
end
```

In your form:

> use fields for two separate association as we build on new action.

This is how I would design my form if I were solving this problem.
Benefits:
1. Maintainable Code
2. Less code in controller
3. More agile on unit responsibilities.

Despite considering syntax mistake you can follow this pattern.